# How to make Block Container with Inline-Block Child in CSS

Tags: css

I have this problem going on:

[image: CSS should be block but became inline-block]

This is the format in which the relationship heirarchy parent-child is maintained.

```
<div class="ContainerTitle">SYLLABUS:
<div class="DownloadThis"></div>
<div class="ViewThis"></div>
<div class="showHint"></div>
</div>
```

- I wanted the property of inline-block for **.DownloadThis** and **.ViewThis** so I defined them as **inline-block**.
- I have defined **.ContainerTitle** as **block**
- However, the property of **.ContainerTitle** over there in the screenshot can be clearly observed as **inline-block**
- What is happening? Why is my child container overriding the definition of its parent?(or is this really happening?? or something else?)

### What I want to do:

- Make .ContainerTitle a display:block so that the next **<div>Sixth (6th) Semester</div>** containers will go to the next line... instead of sticking to the previous container awkwardly!
- I want the whole .ContainerTitle to behave as a block and then all the divs inside it to behave as inline-block

### I want to get a result like this:

[image: Result]

> Below is my snippet. Please look at it and tell me what needs to be done :)

```css
.ContainerTitle {
  display: block; 
  /* WHY IS THIS^ NOT WORKING?????*/
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  font-size: Large;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .1s ease-out;
}
.DownloadThis,
.ViewThis {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  width: 40px;
}
.showHint {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  transition: all .9 ease-out;
}
.ContainerTitle:hover .showHint:after {
  content: '*Hint: Hint Text';
  transition: all .9 ease-out;
}
.ViewThis:hover + .showHint:after {
  content: '*Hint: View Online';
  transition: all .9 ease-out;
}
.DownloadThis:hover ~ .showHint:after {
  content: '*Hint: Download This';
  transition: all .9 ease-out;
}
.DownloadThis {
  background: #1D9C73;
  color: #fff;
}
.ViewThis {
  background: #7D529E;
  color: #fff;
}
.DownloadThis:hover,
.ViewThis:hover {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  background: #fff;
}
.DownloadThis:hover {
  color: #1D9C73;
}
.ViewThis:hover {
  color: #7D529E;
}
.ContainerTitle:before,
.DownloadThis:before,
.ViewThis:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  font-size: 32px;
}
.ContainerTitle:before {
  content: '\f0f6';
  font-size: 24px;
}
.DownloadThis:before {
  content: '\f019';
}
.ViewThis:before {
  content: '\f06e';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="ContainerTitle">TESTING:
  <div class="DownloadThis"></div>
  <div class="ViewThis"></div>
  <div class="showHint"></div>
</div>

<div style="background: #4399CD; padding: 30px; color: #fff;display:inline-block;padding-left: 15px; ">
  Sixth (6th) Semester
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.ContainerTitle {
  display: block; 
  /* WHY IS THIS^ NOT WORKING?????*/
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  font-size: Large;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .1s ease-out;
}
.DownloadThis,
.ViewThis {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  width: 40px;
}
.showHint {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  transition: all .9 ease-out;
}
.ContainerTitle:hover .showHint:after {
  content: '*Hint: Hint Text';
  transition: all .9 ease-out;
}
.ViewThis:hover + .showHint:after {
  content: '*Hint: View Online';
  transition: all .9 ease-out;
}
.DownloadThis:hover ~ .showHint:after {
  content: '*Hint: Download This';
  transition: all .9 ease-out;
}
.DownloadThis {
  background: #1D9C73;
  color: #fff;
}
.ViewThis {
  background: #7D529E;
  color: #fff;
}
.DownloadThis:hover,
.ViewThis:hover {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  background: #fff;
}
.DownloadThis:hover {
  color: #1D9C73;
}
.ViewThis:hover {
  color: #7D529E;
}
.ContainerTitle:before,
.DownloadThis:before,
.ViewThis:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  font-size: 32px;
}
.ContainerTitle:before {
  content: '\f0f6';
  font-size: 24px;
}
.DownloadThis:before {
  content: '\f019';
}
.ViewThis:before {
  content: '\f06e';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="ContainerTitle">TESTING:
  <div class="DownloadThis"></div>
  <div class="ViewThis"></div>
  <div class="showHint"></div>
</div>

<div style="background: #4399CD; padding: 30px; color: #fff;display:inline-block;padding-left: 15px; clear:both; float:left">
  Sixth (6th) Semester
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following css in your div(**`<div>Sixth (6th) Semester</div>`**):

```
clear:both; 
float:left;
```

Comment: your answer is exactly to the point. I like that but for the sake of future readers, I am marking @krishna 's anaswer because it has a snippet which will be useful to see the output. Also, he answered first. Please don't mind and thanks for the answer +1 :)